# How to store JSON with value as sentence in HTML data attribute?

Tags: jquery, json, html

**Problem**: Storing JSON response with value more than one word in data-attribute causes problem. It ignores text after curly braces as a value in data-attribute. Sometimes it also ignores text after space character. It considers the remaining text as an attribute.
  when I get a value of data-action it shows only "{".

**sample code** It looks like this.

```
var responseString = [{
                      "key1": "Let's go"
                    },{
                      "key2": "new text"
                    }];
$.each(responseString, function(index, value) {
    childDiv += '<div data-action="' + JSON.stringify(value) + '">CONTENT</div>';
})

$(body).append(childDiv);
```

Comment: displayed value will be [Object object]. Try `childDiv += '<div data-action="' + value.toString() + '">CONTENT</div>';` or `childDiv += '<div data-action="' + value[Object.keys(value)[0]] + '">CONTENT</div>';`

Comment: I used JSON.stringify. I updated question.

Comment: Try second suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you have `'` on your string, you have to `escape` the string before you concatenate.

The you can use `unescape` if you are using the data. Click the element to get the `data` value.

Please see example below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var responseString = [{
    "key1": "Let's go"
  }, {
    "key2": "new text"
  }];
  var childDiv = "";
  $.each(responseString, function(index, value) {
    childDiv += '<div data-action="' + escape(JSON.stringify(value)) + '" >CONTENT</div>';
  });

  $("body").append(childDiv);

  $("body").on('click', 'div', function(event) {
    console.log(unescape($(this).data("action")));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This really helped me. I searched the whole StackOverflow but couldn't find anything. Thanks a lot.